# 未登録で投票しようとしたときに出るダイアログが一部英語

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

アカウント未登録で投票、コメントなどをしようとすると次のようなダイアログが出ます。
そのダイアログが一部英語です。
[image: ダイアログ]
英語

> This site is free and open to everyone, but our registered users can earn extra privileges like posting, commenting, and voting.

翻訳案

> このサイトは無料で誰もが利用可能です。アカウントを登録すると投稿やコメント、投票をすることができます。

---

This string on the signup page is in English and does not exist in Transifex:

> This site is free and open to everyone, but our registered users can earn extra privileges like posting, commenting, and voting.

The Japanese should be this:

> コミュニティに参加してポイントを貯めることで、投稿やコメント、投票といった機能が使えるようになります。

Comment: @jmac Transifexにフレーズがあったので翻訳しました

Comment: @unarist ありがとうございます！適用しましたので、次回のビルドで反映します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実際のところアカウントを作ったばかりではコメントや投票はできないですし、アクションを取ろうとしている人に「このサイトは無料です」って今更感がありますし、個人的には

> コミュニティに参加して「信用度」と呼ばれるポイントを貯めることで、投稿やコメント、投票といった機能が使えるようになります。

ぐらいに書き換えてしまってもと思いました。意訳にもほどがありますが。

Comment: まあ確かにプラス投票は15、コメントは50、マイナス投票が125の信用度ですからね。 でもそれならポイントは別に信用度でもいいと思います。

Comment: 信用度って書くとわかりにくいだろうか・・・という。